# Printing a sorted array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting, loops

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SkihopperOpgave
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string deltagerNavn = " ";
        int hopLængde = 0;
        string[] deltager = new string[5];
        int[] hopLængder = new int[5];
        string[] pladsNumre = new string[5] { "1. ", "2. ", "3. ", "4. ", "5. " };

        for (int i = 0; i < deltager.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Indtast deltagernavn: ");
            deltager[i] = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Indtast hoplængde for deltager: ");
            hopLængder[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            for (int j = hopLængder.Length-1; j>0; j--) //Bubblesort
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                {
                    int b = hopLængder[k];
                    hopLængder[k] = hopLængder[k+1];
                    hopLængder[k+1] = b;
                }
            }
            for (int s = 0; s < deltager.Length; s++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pladsNumre[s] + hopLængder[s] + deltager[s]);
            }


        }

    }
}
}
```

I am trying to create a program that prints out a sorted list of Ski jumpers (deltagere), by sorting their jump distance (hoplængde). What happens is that the user first types in the name of the ski jumper, then the jump distance. The program should then print out a sorted list in this format: 1. 80 John (Newline) 2. 45 Mark... etc.

Each time a user types in a ski jumper, the list should be printed, with all the distances sorted in a descending order.
I've created an array for both names of the ski jumpers and their distances, but I am having trouble as to how I connect the first element in the `int` array with the first element in the string array and how to correctly sort this in each iteration. 
I tried creating a bubblesort for the job, but I get wrong results.

Comment: Is this homework ;) ?

Comment: First of all, your bubble sort is not correct, it always switches the order of the elements, no matter how they compare with each other. Then if you need to switch places on two length indexes, then you also need to switch the names on the same indexes (so the name and length use the same positions).

Comment: Just a short hint (the rest is YOUR homework): create a class "Hopper" with name and distance. Create a List<Hopper>(), fill it with .Add(new Hopper(name, distance)) after entering the values to temporary variables and then use .Sort() to sort the list.

Comment: @DaveBish Why does it matter whether it is homework or not, he needs help anyways.

Comment: @idish because the solution would not be reimplementing bubble-sort and to simply use the native sorting methods and/or extensions.

Comment: @DavidHughes Ah I understand now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at overloads of static method Array.Sort() - it can do what you want.

Also you should read about SortedList<> class - it is probably even better option for your task and use comments already posted (by Fischerman) to declare an entity class.

I think that's enough hints for a homework =)